# How to inspect java bytecode generated by Clojure from the repl?

Tags: java, clojure, bytecode

I couldn't find much information on this topic.  It looks like jswat can be used to accomplish this, but I couldn't find any step-by-step tutorials.

Comment: Have you tried `javap` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the no-disassemble library for this. https://github.com/gtrak/no.disassemble

Add as a plugin in your Leiningen project: `:plugins [[lein-nodisassemble "0.1.3"]]`

```
=> (use 'no.disassemble)
nil
=> (println (disassemble (fn [] (+ 1 2))))
// Compiled from form-init9238501799627991.clj (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public final class vecperf.bench$eval1426$fn__1427 extends clojure.lang.AFunction {

  // Field descriptor #7 Lclojure/lang/Var;
  public static final clojure.lang.Var const__0;

  // Field descriptor #9 Ljava/lang/Object;
  public static final java.lang.Object const__1;

  // Field descriptor #9 Ljava/lang/Object;
  public static final java.lang.Object const__2;

  // Method descriptor #12 ()V
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 0
  public static {};
     0  ldc <String "clojure.core"> [14]
     2  ldc <String "+"> [16]
     4  invokestatic clojure.lang.RT.var(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) : clojure.lang.Var [22]
     7  checkcast clojure.lang.Var [24]
    10  putstatic vecperf.bench$eval1426$fn__1427.const__0 : clojure.lang.Var [26]
    13  lconst_1
    14  invokestatic java.lang.Long.valueOf(long) : java.lang.Long [32]
    17  putstatic vecperf.bench$eval1426$fn__1427.const__1 : java.lang.Object [34]
    20  ldc2_w <Long 2> [35]
    23  invokestatic java.lang.Long.valueOf(long) : java.lang.Long [32]
    26  putstatic vecperf.bench$eval1426$fn__1427.const__2 : java.lang.Object [38]
    29  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 1]

  // Method descriptor #12 ()V
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 1
  public bench$eval1426$fn__1427();
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  invokespecial clojure.lang.AFunction() [41]
    4  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 1]

  // Method descriptor #43 ()Ljava/lang/Object;
  // Stack: 4, Locals: 1
  public java.lang.Object invoke();
     0  lconst_1
     1  ldc2_w <Long 2> [35]
     4  invokestatic clojure.lang.Numbers.add(long, long) : long [49]
     7  invokestatic clojure.lang.Numbers.num(long) : java.lang.Number [53]
    10  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 1]
        [pc: 0, line: 1]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.Object

}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this: https://github.com/nathanmarz/serializable-fn

from readme demo:

```
(use 'serializable.fn)

;; note that this function being created has a function value in its closure
(def f (let [x + c 2]
          (fn [a b] (x a b c))))

(println (f 1 2))

;; 5

(def b (serialize f))

(println (seq b))

;; (0 0 0 2 0 0 0 -79 0 0 0 2 0 1 99 0 0 0 90 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 82 -84 -19 0 5 115 114 0 14 106 97 118 97 46 108 97 110 103 46 76 111 110 103 59 -117 -28 -112 -52 -113 35 -33 2 0 1 74 0 5 118 97 108 117 101 120 114 0 16 106 97 118 97 46 108 97 110 103 46 78 117 109 98 101 114 -122 -84 -107 29 11 -108 -32 -117 2 0 0 120 112 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 120 0 0 0 25 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 17 0 12 99 108 111 106 117 114 101 46 99 111 114 101 0 1 43 0 4 117 115 101 114 0 36 40 115 101 114 105 97 108 105 122 97 98 108 101 46 102 110 47 102 110 32 91 97 32 98 93 32 40 120 32 97 32 98 32 99 41 41)

;; now, restart the repl

(def b
(byte-array (map byte '(0 0 0 2 0 0 0 -79 0 0 0 2 0 1 99 0 0 0 90 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 82 -84 -19 0 5 115 114 0 14 106 97 118 97 46 108 97 110 103 46 76 111 110 103 59 -117 -28 -112 -52 -113 35 -33 2 0 1 74 0 5 118 97 108 117 101 120 114 0 16 106 97 118 97 46 108 97 110 103 46 78 117 109 98 101 114 -122 -84 -107 29 11 -108 -32 -117 2 0 0 120 112 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 120 0 0 0 25 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 17 0 12 99 108 111 106 117 114 101 46 99 111 114 101 0 1 43 0 4 117 115 101 114 0 36 40 115 101 114 105 97 108 105 122 97 98 108 101 46 102 110 47 102 110 32 91 97 32 98 93 32 40 120 32 97 32 98 32 99 41 41))))

(use 'serializable.fn)

(def f (deserialize b))

(println f 1 2)

;; 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [cider-decompile](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider-decompile). Useful only if your editor is Emacs, since it is an extension to the  Clojure IDE and REPL for Emacs (built on top of nREPL).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the javap -c command : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html